# Real time multi threaded max-heap for top-N geohash

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, heap, real-time, binary-heap

There is a requirement to keep a list of top-10 localities in a city from where demand for our food service is emanating at any given instant. The city could have tens of thousands of localities. 
If one has to make a near real time (lag no more than 5 minutes) datastore in memory that would 
- keep count of incoming demand by locality (geo hash)
- reads by hundreds of our suppliers every minute (the ajax refresh is every minute)

I was thinking of a multi threaded synchronized max-heap. This would be a complex solution as tree locking is by itself a complex implementation.

Any recommendations for the best in-memory (replicatable master slave) data structure that can be read and updated in multi threaded environment?

We expect 10K QPS and 100K updates per second. When we scale to other cities and regions, we will need per city implementation of top-10.

Are there any off the shelf solutions available?

Persistence is not a need so no mySQL based solutions. If you recommend redis or mongo DB solution, please realize that the queries are not pointed-queries by key but a top-N query instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for exactly what you're describing, there are a few approaches that might work nicely. There are several papers describing concurrent data structures that could work as priority queues; [here is one option](http://www.non-blocking.com/download/SunT03_PQueue_TR.pdf) that I'm not super familiar with but which looks promising. You might also want to check out concurrent skip lists, which should also match your requirements.

If I'm interpreting your problem statement correctly, you're hoping to maintain a top-10 list of locations based on the number of hits you receive. If that's the case, I would suspect that while the number of updates would be huge, the number of times that two locations would switch positions would not actually be all that large. In other words, most updates wouldn't actually require the data structure to change shape. Consequently, you could consider using a standard binary heap where each element uses an atomic-compare-and-set integer key and where you have some kind of locking system that's used only in the case where you need to add, move, or delete an element from the heap.

Given the scale that you're working at, you may also want to consider approximate solutions to your problem. The [count-min sketch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch) data structure, for example, was specifically designed to estimate frequent elements in a data stream and does so extremely quickly. It can easily be distributed and linked up with a priority queue in a manner similar to what I described above. There are lots of good implementations out there, and if I remember correctly this data structure is actually deployed in situations like the one you're describing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using geohashes and skip lists. But I find in my case because of the difference between two geohashes is very large most of my range queries happen on the lowest level list. I do not get any hits on any of the fast lanes